# Why did moderators unilaterally delete some of my accepted opened questions?

Tags: discussion

If I remember, these questions

- were open at the time of their closure
- were not closed by the usual 5 votes.

I accepted some of them, and some were upvoted. Most were answered by other users very helpfully, and their answers were upvoted. In some, the images are mine or my family's, which ought substantiate my questions' legitimacy.

BrettfromLA deleted

https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/23912 and https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/24033 for they "Does not seem to need a life hack".
https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/23926 for being a duplicate.

Chenmunka deleted

https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/23853 for "This question doesn't seem to be about a problem".
https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/18702 for "Does not seem to need a life hack".
https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/18724. I don't see a close reason.

I don't see any explanations e.g. why the moderator believed my question doesn't seem to need life hacks or be about a problem.

I'm happy to prove these are legitimate questions that do need life hacks and that are problems, if anyone can recommend how.

Answer (score 7):

Your post can be read two ways.

1. “I think moderators have been abusing their powers when unilaterally closing and/or deleting my posts.” Or
2. “I disagree with multiple closures.”

In case of 1:
A moderator has exactly the same right as any user with sufficient reputation to vote to close and/or delete a question. The difference between a moderator and a regular user is that a moderator’s vote is binding, whereas sans moderator votes a post needs at least five standard close votes. The instructions given to moderators are very clear and can be paraphrased as “when you see something that should be closed, vote to close - just as you would as regular user”. Same goes for deletion. The reasons are given in the header, as you wrote yourself. There is no requirement to explain beyond the standardized messages - in fact, that’s why the standard closure reasons exist. They *are the explanation why the post was closed.* While on some of the larger sites moderators *may* hold back until some community votes are cast (for various reasons, the details don’t matter here), this is certainly not mandatory and for smaller sites with a less broad and active user base, moderator activity must fill the gaps. There is no abuse of power in this approach. For deletion, your acceptance will prevent a community deletion of a post, but not a moderator deletion. Also perfectly fine and in accordance with the rules.

In case of 2:
Don’t ask multiple questions (or rather *about* multiple questions) in one post. That would be a reason to close this question as “needs more focus”.